# Odd C# behavior when implementing generic interface

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, interface

Given this "IHandle" interface and two classes to be handled:

```
interface IHandle<T>
{
  void Handle(T m);
}


class M1
{
  public int Id;
}


class MReset
{
}
```

I want to create a generic base that takes care of "resetting" as well as managing M1 instances:

```
class HandlerBase<T> :
  IHandle<MReset>,
  IHandle<T> where T : M1
{
  protected int Count;

  void IHandle<T>.Handle(T m)
  {
    ++Count;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Count = {0}", m.Id, Count);
  }


  void IHandle<MReset>.Handle(MReset m)
  {
    Count = 0;
  }
}
```

This does not compile since the compiler believes T could be "MReset" so it outputs:

> error CS0695: 'HandlerBase' cannot implement both 'IHandle'
>   and 'IHandle' because they may unify for some type parameter
>   substitutions

That in itself is slightly odd since I cannot see how T could possibly be of type MReset since it must be of type M1. But okay, I can accept that the compiler is smarter than me :-)

**Edit**: The compiler is not smarter than me :-) According to a comment on [Why does this result in CS0695?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316898/why-does-this-result-in-cs0695) we have "Constraint declarations are not considered when determining all possible constructed types".

Now I swap the interface declarations:

```
class HandlerBase<T> :
  IHandle<T> where T : M1,
  IHandle<MReset>
{
  ... same as before ..
}
```

And suddenly I get a different error message stating that I cannot implement IHandle.Handle(MReset m) since the class declaration does not state that it is implementing that interface:

> error CS0540: 'HandlerBase.IHandle<...>.Handle(MReset)': containing
>   type does not implement interface 'IHandle'

**Question**: why does the order of declarations make such a difference? What is going wrong in the second example?

In the end it turns out that there is a solution:

```
class HandlerBase :
  IHandle<MReset>
{
  protected int Count;


  void IHandle<MReset>.Handle(MReset m)
  {
    Count = 0;
  }
}


class Handler<T> : HandlerBase,
  IHandle<T> where T : M1
{
  void IHandle<T>.Handle(T m)
  {
    ++Count;
    Console.WriteLine("{0}: Count = {0}", m.Id, Count);
  }
}
```

But the solution only works if `HandlerBase` implements `IHandle<MReset>` - not if the generic interface `IHandle<T>` is implemented in `HandlerBase` first. **Why**?

**Edit**: Implementing `IHandle<T>` in `HandlerBase` *does* work (and if I had shown the code someone might have seen it). This works:

```
class HandlerBase<T> :
  IHandle<T> where T : M1
{
  protected int Count;

  void IHandle<T>.Handle(T m)
  {
    ++Count;
    Console.WriteLine("Type = {0}, Id = {1}, Count = {2}", GetType(), m.Id, Count);
  }
}


class Handler<T> : HandlerBase<T>,
  IHandle<MReset>
  where T : M1
{
  void IHandle<MReset>.Handle(MReset m)
  {
    Count = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("RESET");
  }
}
```

Unfortunately my second class declaration was this:

```
class Handler<T> : HandlerBase<T> where T : M1,
  IHandle<MReset>
{
  void IHandle<MReset>.Handle(MReset m)
  {
    Count = 0;
    Console.WriteLine("RESET");
  }
}
```

Notice the subtle difference in the location of `where T : M1` :-) The last example declares that T must implement `IHandle<MReset>` (in addition to `M1`). Duh!

Comment: [Related / Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316898/why-does-this-result-in-cs0695). I'm not closing as duplicate just because of this question "why does the order of declarations make such a difference?" which isn't answered there.

Comment: That is indeed the relevant link. I just edited the accepted answer there in order to make the important piece of information from the C# spec more visible: **"Constraint declarations are not considered when determining all possible constructed types."**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved - I found the subtle difference. When the order of declarations is swapped I should *not* move `where T : M1` since the `IHandle<MReset>` constraint then ends up being applied to T instead of the class declaration:

```
class HandlerBase<T> :
  IHandle<T> where T : M1,
  IHandle<MReset>
{
  ... same as before ..
}
```

The correct re-ordering should have been:

```
class HandlerBase<T> :
  IHandle<T>,
  IHandle<MReset>
  where T : M1
{
  ... same as before ..
}
```

Answer (score 1):

@Siram pointed out that the uniqueness problem (but not the order aspect) has been answered in [Why does this result in CS0695?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15316898/why-does-this-result-in-cs0695):

The C# language spec (https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=7029) discusses the "Uniqueness of implemented interfaces" in 13.4.2.: "The interfaces implemented by a generic type declaration must remain unique for all possible constructed types." And later, when describing the details of the check: **"Constraint declarations are not considered** when determining all possible constructed types."

Why that is so I am not sure; perhaps one can construct nested or chained constraints which make it impossible for the compiler to prove uniqueness, or not all constraints can be communicated via assemblies (which, I think, would be necessary for the general language rule).

Comment: Thanks for highlighting "Constraint declarations are not considered when determining all possible constructed types." - that explains parts of it. I am though still most confused about the order aspect (as I can see both you and Siram are aware of).

Comment: Apparently the compiler *does* consider constraint declarations in some unexpected way. If I remove `where T : M1` then the order of declarations becomes insignificant and both sequences result in CS0695 "... because they may unify for some type parameter substitutions" - as I would expect.